# Sum of Totals for Row Grand Totals bar in Stacked Bar in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have created a stacked bar and included 'Row Grand Totals' to the view, further to this have made use of 'Add Reference Line' option and brought Grand Totals for each of stacked bar. But could not bring Grand Totals for the bar which is a Row Grand Total.

In the below image, 'All Business' is the 'Row Grand Totals' to which I need Grand Totals on top of the bar.

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this requirement?

Comment: if you add a reference line then that should be also available to Row Grand Totals aswell. If not then explain how you created All Business stacked bar

Comment: @Siva - 'All Business' is a result of Row Grand Totals, but Reference Line doesn't seem to work for Grand Totals, you may try an example on small data set

Comment: Yes I have tried and I was able to see the grand totals at the top of total bar chart.

Comment: @Siva - Thank you so much for testing, could you pls let me know the steps to arrive the output, that would be great!

Comment: I am not sure how you have arrived ad `All Business` bar, But what I have done is to get the `All Business` part is to insert the `Row Grand Totals` and then add the reference line which have automatically added the total to `All Business` bar aswell. Have you followed the same process or any other way?

Comment: @Siva - I have followed the same steps but again I did not get totals on top of Row Totals bar - could you share the steps through which you arrived also with an image?

Comment: sure give me some time will share you the file if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am unable to attach a workbook here but attaching the screenshot.

If you have any shared drive share the link will send the book aswell, But for now check the image. Data is from sample super store data sheet.

[image]

Check total bar in image.

Edit.......
Download the report from below link with in 24 hrs:

https://dropfile.to/mZdagLD

//Tableau version 10.4

Comment: Yes Siva, this is what I am not getting on my graph...please share the workbook to my mail ID chandanmiles@gmail.com